# Cmd commands with spaces from VBscript

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I'm trying to execute a SAS code with VBScript through the command line. However, I'm having issues with passing the commands from VBScript to command line properly. I'm pretty sure it is a matter of using quotes and `chr(34)` correctly, but I cannot figure it out.

So I want to run the follow command in command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\SAS 9.4\sas.exe" -SYSIN "C:\Program Files\test.sas"
```

I've tried something like

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /K copy ""C:\Program Files\SAS 9.4\sas.exe"" -SYSIN ""C:\Program Files\test.sas"" ", 1, True
Set oShell = Nothing
```

But I get an invalid syntax error in command line. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD /K` expects a single argument.  If the argument contains spaces, the argument must be quoted.  So the full command would be something like:

```
oShell.run "cmd.exe /K "" ""C:\Program Files\SAS 9.4\sas.exe"" -SYSIN ""C:\Program Files\test.sas"" "" ", 1, True
```

Normally, one would have to worry about nested quoting/escapes, but the /C and /K switches are special in how quotes work (`CMD /?` explains the details).  If it looks like a single quoted argument, any quotes inside are automatically ignored by `CMD`.

Comment: Oh yeah I got confused from trying to google. So the command I want to execute is just

`oShell.run "cmd.exe /K "" ^""C:\Program Files\SAS 9.4\sas.exe^"" -SYSIN ^""C:\Program Files\test.sas^"" "" ", 1, True`

As this should run the test.sas file in command line. However, the above doesn't work. I get an error with

` '"C:\Program' 
`
which I think indicates the quoting isn't workin :-/

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I got it wrong myself.  `CMD /K` has special behavior regarding quotes, that isn't seen anywhere else in CMD, and which I forgot about.  I have corrected the original answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much - now my work will be much simpler ;-)